# Make string replacements using an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, associative-array

I have an associative array where keys are search strings and values are replacement strings.

```
$list = ['hi' => 0, 'man' => 1];
$string = "hi man, how are you? man is here. hi again."
```

**It should produce**:

```
$final_string = "0 1, how are you? 1 is here. 0 again."
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `$newString = str_replace(array_keys($list), array_values($list), $string);` or `$newString = strtr($string, $list);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Off of the top of my head:

```
$find       = array_keys($list);
$replace    = array_values($list);
$new_string = str_ireplace($find, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob, but it does not work and still some mistake, `$keys` should be `$replace`.

Comment: @srain You made a good point about case sensitivity. But that is easily remedied by using the case insensitive version of `str_replace()`, `str_ireplace()`

Comment: `$replace = array_values($list);` call to `array_values` is not necessary, you can just pass the `$list` array to `str_replace`.

Answer (score 18):

Can be done in one line using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/strtr).

Quoting the documentation:

> If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the form `array('from' => 'to', ...)`. The return value is a string where all the occurrences of the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values. The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

To get the modified string, you'd just do:

```
$newString = strtr($string, $list);
```

This would output:

```
0 1, how are you? 1 is here. 0 again.
```

[Demo.](https://eval.in/72020)

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? This function is designed to do exactly what the OP (and I) is looking for.

Comment: @scipilot: It's [The Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem :)

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` may be helpful.

```
<?php
$list = Array
(
    'hi' => 0,
    'man' => 1
);
$string="hi man, how are you? Man is here. Hi again.";

$patterns = array();
$replacements = array();

foreach ($list as $k => $v)
{
    $patterns[] = '/' . $k . '/i';  // use i to ignore case
    $replacements[] = $v;
}
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Comment: I might be inclined to use array_map() to wrap the keys with delimiters rather than a foreach() loop; but it does handle case sensitivity; and could even be tweaked to handle word boundaries as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = strtr($text, $array_from_to)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: Very simple solution that works great. Thank you.